# Merge Objects based on Conditions in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm building a project with Laravel 8. I need to merge multiple objects but with conditions. Here is my final object.

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "code": 200,
    "data": {
        "invoices": [
            {
                "invoice_id": 6366,
                "issue_date": "2020-07-22",
                "invoice_status": "Fully Paid",
                "installment_count": 4,
                "services_total_price": 0,
                "services": [
                    {
                        "invoice_service_name": "Bathroom Pack",
                        "invoice_service_price": 0
                    }
                ],
                "installments": [
                    {
                        "payment_id": 47687,
                        "invoice_id": 6366,
                        "payment_amount": "3900.00",
                        "paid_amount": "3900.00",
                        "outstanding_amount": "0.00",
                        "due_date": "2020-08-25",
                        "installment_status": "Fully Paid"
                    },
                    {
                        "payment_id": 47688,
                        "invoice_id": 6366,
                        "payment_amount": "3900.00",
                        "paid_amount": "3900.00",
                        "outstanding_amount": "0.00",
                        "due_date": "2020-10-26",
                        "installment_status": "Fully Paid"
                    },
                    {
                        "payment_id": 47689,
                        "invoice_id": 6366,
                        "payment_amount": "3900.00",
                        "paid_amount": "2400.00",
                        "outstanding_amount": "1500.00",
                        "due_date": "2020-12-28",
                        "installment_status": "Partially Paid"
                    },
                    {
                        "payment_id": 47690,
                        "invoice_id": 6366,
                        "payment_amount": "3900.00",
                        "paid_amount": "0.00",
                        "outstanding_amount": "3900.00",
                        "due_date": "2021-02-26",
                        "installment_status": "Unpaid"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "invoice_id": 6058,
                "issue_date": "2020-06-12",
                "invoice_status": "Fully Paid",
                "installment_count": 0,
                "services_total_price": null,
                "services": [],
                "installments": [
                    {
                        "payment_id": 41306,
                        "invoice_id": 6058,
                        "payment_amount": "1168.00",
                        "paid_amount": "1168.00",
                        "outstanding_amount": "0.00",
                        "due_date": "2020-06-12",
                        "installment_status": "Fully Paid"
                    }
                ]
            },
```

The best way I found is;

```
        $invoices = DB::connection('mysql2')->select(
            'SELECT i.invoice_id,
                        i.issue_date,
                        i.invoice_status,
                        i.issue_date,
                        i.installment_count,
 ic.invoice_course_start_date) AS total_days
                    FROM students AS s
                            JOIN invoices AS i ON s.student_id = i.student_id
                            JOIN invoices_courses AS ic ON i.invoice_id = ic.invoice_id
                            JOIN currencies c on i.currency_id = c.currency_id
                    WHERE s.student_id = 237
ORDER BY i.invoice_id DESC
');

        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($invoices); $i++) {
            $invoices[$i]->currency_symbol = utf8_encode($invoices[$i]->currency_symbol)

            $installments = DB::connection('mysql3')->select('SELECT ip.payment_id,
       ip.invoice_id,
       ip.payment_amount,
       ip.paid_amount,
       ip.outstanding_amount,
              ip.due_date,
       IF(ip.outstanding_amount = 0, "Fully Paid", IF(ip.outstanding_amount = ip.payment_amount, "Unpaid" , "Partially Paid")) AS installment_status
FROM invoices_payments AS ip
WHERE payment_type != "deposit"
  AND ip.invoice_id = ?', [$invoices[$i]->invoice_id]);

            $services = DB::connection('mysql3')->select('SELECT invoice_service_name, invoice_service_price
FROM invoices_services
WHERE invoice_id = ?', [$invoices[$i]->invoice_id]);

            $services_total_price = DB::connection('mysql3')->select('SELECT SUM(invoice_service_price) AS total
FROM invoices_services
WHERE invoice_id = ?', [$invoices[$i]->invoice_id]);

            $invoices[$i]->deposit_outstanding = $invoices[$i]->deposit_amount - $invoices[$i]->deposit_paid_amount;
            $invoices[$i]->discount = $invoices[$i]->gross_price - $invoices[$i]->price;
            $invoices[$i]->services_total_price = $services_total_price[0]->total;
            $invoices[$i]->services = $services;
            $invoices[$i]->installments = $installments;
```

But it takes too long. To send a request database for each invoice is too much. Then I use IN inside SQL syntax.

```
       ip.invoice_id,
       ip.payment_amount,
       ip.paid_amount,
       ip.outstanding_amount,
              ip.due_date,
       IF(ip.outstanding_amount = 0, "Fully Paid", IF(ip.outstanding_amount = ip.payment_amount, "Unpaid" , "Partially Paid")) AS installment_status
FROM invoices_payments AS ip
WHERE payment_type != "deposit"
  AND ip.invoice_id = ?', [$invoice_ids]);

        $services = DB::connection('mysql3')->select('SELECT invoice_service_name, invoice_service_price
FROM invoices_services
WHERE invoice_id = ?', [$invoice_ids]);

        $services_total_price = DB::connection('mysql3')->select('SELECT SUM(invoice_service_price) AS total
FROM invoices_services
WHERE invoice_id = ?', [$invoice_ids]);
```

But as you notice this gives me all installments and other stuff. How can I merge invoices and others with conditions? Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about using Eloquent:

```
class Invoice extends Model
{
    // ...
    public function services()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\Services::class);
    }

    public function installments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\Installment::class);
    }

    public function student()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Student::class);
    }
    // ...
}
```

So you can access it like this:

```
Invoice::with(['services', 'installments'])->whereHas('student.student_id', 237)->get();
```

Some dynamic properties might be done as [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor)

Comment: What's more interesting/challenging is that _(`invoices` & `students`)_ tables (`DB: mysql2`) and _(`invoices_payments`(instalments) & `invoices_services`(services))_ tables (`DB: mysql3`) appear to exist in different databases.

Comment: One caveat I noticed is that [Eloquent does not currently support querying for relationship existence across databases](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence). Maybe not important for this particular scenario, I just wanted the OP to be aware of that. That applies to `Model::whereHas` & `Model::has` & `Model::orHas` **not working** as expected.

Comment: You can at least have [different connections for different models](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#database-connections)

Comment: @shaedrich I merged the databases, that gives me the answer, thanks